# Custom text labels in plotly pie chart

Tags: python, plotly

I'm trying to add custom text inside of a plotly pie chart.

I want the largest share to be labeled Rank 1, second largest Rank 2, and so on...

Is there any way to do this using the `texttemplate` or some other method?

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
labels = list('ABCD')
values = [25,45,13,78]
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Pie(labels=labels, values=values,
                      texttemplate=("Rank %i" % 1))])
fig.show()
```

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need this function:

```
def get_ranks(lst, begin_with_one=False):
    srtd = sorted(lst, reverse=True)
    res = [srtd.index(x) for x in lst]
    return [x + 1 for x in res] if begin_with_one else res
```

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
labels = list('ABCD')
values = [25,45,13,78]
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Pie(labels=labels, values=values,
                      texttemplate=[f"Rank {x}" for x in get_ranks(values, begin_with_one=True)])])
fig.show()
```

Use as often as possible the f-strings in Python3 - they are super convenient!

Since this works only with unique list elements, I created a better index assessor:

```
def map_to_index(lst1, lst2):
    """Return lst1 as indexes of lst2"""
    dct = {}
    for i, x in enumerate(lst2):
        dct[x] = dct.get(x, []) + [i]
    indexes = []
    for x in lst1:
        indexes.append(dct[x][0])
        if len(dct[x]) > 0:
            dct[x] = dct[x][1:]
    return indexes
```

And an improved `get_ranks()`:

```
def get_ranks(lst, begin_with_one=False):
    srtd = sorted(lst, reverse=True)
    res = map_to_index(lst, srtd)
    return [x + 1 for x in res] if begin_with_one else res
```

Then it works also with:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
labels = list('ABCDEF')
values = [25,45,13,78,45,78] # with elements of same value
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Pie(labels=labels, values=values,
                      texttemplate=[f"Rank {x}" for x in get_ranks(values, begin_with_one=True)])])
fig.show()
```

Comment: In `get_ranks()` you can just do `srtd = sorted(lst, reverse=True)` saves creating multiple lists I think.

Comment: @TomMyddeltyn Yes true! Problem however is, that it works only with unique values ...

Comment: So, now I wrote an improved version which works also when in the values list several elements have the same value.

Answer (score 1):

Passing an array to texttemplate helps

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
labels = list('ABCD')
values = [25,45,13,78]
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Pie(labels=labels, values=values,
                      texttemplate=([4,2,3,'Rank 1']))])
fig.show()
```